# Smarty support for Aptana Studio 3

Tags: aptana, aptana3, smarty3

Is there any support for Smarty in Aptana Studio 3? I saw a few question here but they are old enough.

I have searched the websites but didn't got anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a plugin for Aptana 2, but I have never gotten it to work in Aptana 3. From what I can gather (and I searched for quite a while before giving up on Smarty altogether) there is no functional plugin for the moment.

Comment: Although lack of support for Smarty in Aptana was only one small reason to give it up. Smarty not working properly on my production server was a larger one.

Comment: Is there any possibility in future ?
If not then i am gonna change my IDE :( .

Comment: I have no idea. There are great alternatives to Smarty, but I don't know if there are any plugins for them either. Twig seems like a nice alternative to Smarty.